# Setting a python script default when creating a new file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I would like to set a default custom script whenever creating a new .py file or .ipynb file in Pycharm or VS Code.

I would like the default script to load looking as such:

```
import time
import datetime

start = time.time()
# Code here.

end = time.time()
print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=end - start)))
```

Is it possible to set default scripts in IDEs? Many Thanks.

Comment: Consider `VS Code`  `Configuring user code snippets` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to set a new file template. Maybe the code snippet will help you.

> You can easily define your own snippets without any extension. To create or edit your own snippets, select **User Snippets** under **File** > **Preferences** (Code > Preferences on macOS), and then select the language (by [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)) for which the snippets should appear, or the **New Global Snippets** file option if they should appear for all languages. VS Code manages the creation and refreshing of the underlying snippets file(s) for you.

Of course, we choose python here

[image]

Then change the open file to the following.

```json
{
    "time":{
        "prefix": "time",
        "body": [
        "import time",
        "import datetime",
        "start = time.time()",
        "$1",
        "end = time.time()",
        "print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=end - start)))"],
        "description": "",
        "isFileTemplate": true
    }
}
```

Then enter `time` in the **.py** file to get the fragment.

[image]

*More information about the code snippet can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).*